# What is a "clock source"?

Tags: clock

I just encountered the phrase "8254 clock source" in [The Well Grounded Java Developer](http://dl.e-book-free.com/2013/07/the_well-grounded_java_developer.pdf).

Unfortunately, I don't know the definition of 'clock source'.

Is it similar to the [Clock signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_signal) or is it some kind of source code that makes a timer?

The quote from the book is:

> The 8254 is a programmable timer chip that’s been kicking around since
>   the dawn of time. The clock source for this is a 119.318 kHz crystal,
>   which is one-third of the NTSC color subcarrier frequency, for reasons
>   that go back to the CGA graphics system. This is what once was used
>   for feeding regular ticks (for timeslicing) to OS schedulers, but
>   that’s done from elsewhere (or isn’t required) now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the "clock source" is the thing that is providing the "clock signal", which in turn determines the rate at which the 8254 timer counts.

Note that while TWGJD says

> "The clock source for this is a 119.318 kHz crystal"

this doesn't mean that the timer is *necessarily* receiving a clock signal of this frequency: any given design might have dividers between the crystal and the timer chip.